# How to set daylight saving time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, time

Query:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

returns:

```
+01:00, +01:00
```

which is okay, but:

```
SELECT NOW()
```

returns time that was an **hour ago**. So it seems my database it not respecting daylight saving time mode. 
How can I set this mode?

Comment: SET time_zone='system'; they use the system time

Comment: @BerndBuffen Wow, that worked! I tried 'Europe/CITY_HERE' but it didn't accept it. Thanks! Care to post this as an answer?

Comment: @BerndBuffen: Don't `SET time_zone='system'` unless you actually *want* resultset times to be in the system timezone.  @Tom: You probably have [`system_time_zone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone) incorrectly set.

Comment: @eggyal 'Europe/Warsaw' is a correct time_zone name everywhere I tried just not in my MySQL database

Comment: @Tom: And what is `system_time_zone` set to?

Comment: @Tom: So, when you asked for UTC+1, MySQL gave you T-1.  It thinks the system clock is CEST, which is UTC+2.  I'd wager that the system clock is actually UTC+1.  Either change the timezone of the system clock, or correct the value of `system_time_zone`.

Comment: Although, if you're in Warsaw and ***want*** the daylight savings time, then you're actually expecting UTC+2—whereas you requested UTC+1.  So it's no wonder you got back a time that you thought was 1h behind!  You'd just requested the wrong thing.

Comment: @eggyal: The timezone is UTC+1, daylight saving mode adds 1 hour during spring and autumn but it doesn't "really" change the timezone. I cannot just set my script to UTC+1 or UTC+2 because then it will work only half the year. "System" actually works in this case.

Comment: @Tom: But you have set `time_zone` to be UTC+1.  If that's not the timezone you want, then set it to what you actually do want (e.g. Europe/Warsaw, which changes with daylight savings).  Don't rely on the system timezone happening to be the same as what your application wants.

Comment: @eggyal: But it says it doesn't understand "Europe/Warsaw". And in most cases, and surely in mine, the system is in my timezone.

Comment: @Tom: See [Populating the Time Zone Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation).  And I wouldn't rely on that—what if you move the application to be hosted on a different system that's located in a different timezone?  Will you remember to adjust your application accordingly?  Or what if you start hosting different applications, serving users in different timezones?  It's very bad to rely on such a broken approach.

Comment: @eggyal This is actually a worse solution. In 90% cases "system" gives the correct result. And in most cases you do not have root access to the server (shared hostings). I don't. I understand your concerns, they are perfectly valid but in my situation this is the only thing that works.

Comment: @Tom: If you aren't the sysadmin then there's an even greater concern that they might change the system timezone without informing you—which will break your application.  The ***correct*** way is for your application to set the `time_zone` that it wants—if that's a timezone not supported by the server (e.g. because the sysadmin hasn't loaded the timezone files) then that's something you'll need to take up with the sysadmin.  As an alternative workaround, you could also consider requesting times from MySQL in UTC and performing timezone conversion in your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the System-time

```
SET time_zone='system';
```

or global for all

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone='system';
```

Comment: The OP wants UTC+1.  This only works because the system clock happens to be UTC+1, which you cannot have known without inspecting either the system clock or the `system_time_zone` variable.  In any event, it's not a good solution to the problem: what if a different connection wants a time in a different timezone?  It will then get an erroneous result because of the misconfiguration.

Comment: Also beware that the global `time_zone` variable isn't "global for all"—rather it is the default `time_zone` for new connections.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT IF(ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(TIME(SYSDATE()), UTC_TIME())) / 3600, 0) = 2
    , 'summer time', 'winter time') AS time;
```

Comment: Could you please add some information on how this code is answering the question?